# A strange question about copy constructor for QList type instance

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor, qlist

Synopsis of a code is given below to demonstrate the problem, thanks for your time.

1. At `RowOfData rowData = tableData[row];`, `RowOfData` copy constructer will be called and it performs a shallow copy.
2. At `tableData[row][col] = item;`, `QtParameter` copy constructer will be called by `tableData[row][col]` assingment operation and it will be followed by a call to `QList<T>::node_copy` so the new entry `tableData[row][col]` will be assigned.

   - Question:
     why `tableData[row][col]` would call  `QtParameter` copy constructer?
   - BTW, `QtParameter` copy constructer  wouldn't be called for `tableData[row][col]`  when `rowData` is destructed at the end of the function.

Classes:

```
            QtParameter::QtParameter( const QtParameter& rhs) :QVariant(rhs){}

            class RowOfData : QList<QtParameter>
            {
               public:
                  RowOfData(const RowOfData& rhs);                 
               private:            
            }

            class TableData
            {
               public :
                    TableData();
                    virtual ~TableData();
                    bool setItem(int row, int col, QtParameter item);                    
              protected:
                    QStringList         columnHeader;
                    QStringList         rowHeader;
                    QStringList         rowFooter;
                    QList< RowOfData >  tableData;              
            }
```

Member functions:

```
           bool TableData::setItem(int row, int col, QtParameter item)
           {
              if(row<rowCount())     
               {                
                    RowOfData rowData = tableData[row];
            /*useless here and impact the tableData[row][col] copy constructer× */            
                    if( col < tableData.at(row).size() )
                    {
                        tableData[row][col] = item;
                    }
                }
            } 
            template <typename T>
            Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE void QList<T>::node_copy(Node *from, Node *to, Node *src)
            {
                Node *current = from;
                if (QTypeInfo<T>::isLarge || QTypeInfo<T>::isStatic) {
                    QT_TRY {
                        while(current != to) {
                            current->v = new T(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(src->v));
                            ++current;
                            ++src;
                        }
                    } QT_CATCH(...) {
                        while (current-- != from)
                            delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(current->v);
                        QT_RETHROW;
                    }
            ...
            }
```

Comment: I  am considering does   [] operation in "tableData[row][col]" for QList trigger deep copy. however the question is why after remove   RowOfData rowData = tableData[row]; , there is no deep  copy operation.

Comment: I wrote an answer. If it solved the problem please consider voting/accepting it! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is when member function `TableData::setItem` is called by an object of type `QtParameter` , because the function is taking it not by reference, an object of type `QtParameter` has to be created inside the function by copy constructing from the previous one!

If you want to avoid that, take it by reference (preferably const one) :

```
bool TableData::setItem(int row, int col, const QtParameter& item)
```

Moving forward, inside the function at:

```
RowOfData rowData = tableData[row];
```

With a small possibility, if these are not some type/s of iterator/pointer at their lowest level, this also could be the source.

Finally at:

```
tableData[row][col] = item;
```

Based of what you mentioned another possibility could be the way assignment operator itself is defined for the class of `tableData[row][col]`.
Keeping in mind that assignment operator is also a function, if it is not declared like:

```
assigned_to & operator=(const assigned_from &)
```

For example:

```
assigned_to & operator=(assigned_from)
```

Same as the first case an object of assigned_from will be copy constructed inside the assignment operator.

Many information are not given and if by the "Deep copy" you are referring to `QList<T>::node_copy`, the copy constructor can also happen inside that simply at:

```
current->v = new T(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(src->v));
```

Which is a clear call to **a** copy constructor. But since information about the types are not given, I can't say for sure, this is where **the** copy constructor is called.

Also unless you provide some information about `QList<QtParameter>` , there is not much that I can say about why the "Deep copy" didn't take place when `rowData` was destructed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @AKL, still some points not clear 1) actually copy constructer for item object happen when entered the function, 2) deep copy for  tableData[row]  before = opration 3)  why deep copy operation not happen when remove RowOfData rowData = tableData[row]   BTW I tried use reference , the problem still there.

Comment: HI Akl, now I am considering why add RowOfData rowData = tableData[row]; would lead to deep copy for tableData[row], and i have one assume that not for sure, as RowOfData rowData = tableData[row] would call copy constructor, and it is a swallow copy, when exit the function  rowData would release its memory, the compiler may let  tableData[row] do deep copy, otherwise dynamic memory would release. I suppose the compiler impact that, however I am not for sure.

Comment: @water Hi friend let me think for a bit :) Did you try  ```rowData = std::move(tableData[row]) ``` ?

Comment: @water also please try ```RowOfData rowData(std::move(ableData[row])); ```. for  the header ```#include <utility>```

Comment: both rowData = std::move(tableData[row]) , RowOfData rowData(std::move(ableData[row]));  would call RowOfData::RowOfData(const RowOfData& rhs) copy constructor ,then problem still exist, thanks for your suggstions

Comment: Well that is an important indicator! It shows that there is no move constructor (shallow copy)  for the class. So you found the answer! If you want a move constructor(shallow copy) for the class you should write one yourself! Are you satisfied with the conclusion?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and why add move constructor can solve the problem, I mean add move constructor can avoid deep copy for tableData[row][col]. And my question is still there  "why add RowOfData rowData = tableData[row]; would lead to deep copy for tableData[row][col],"

Comment: @water I am a little bit confused. Could you please go over your original question again and try to edit it in order to make it more clear if it is possible? Also I really appreciate it if you can add synopsis(or link to where source can be found) from ```QList``` template and ```QtParameter``` class my friend!

Comment: Hi AKL, Sorry for late response, As the code is not private, so I can not show it to you.And I find some clue today, When do QList<>[] operation, it will call

Comment: @water you mean "the code **is** private", yes? :)  Well that is a good news that you found the problem on your own and well done. Still I appreciate it if you at least vote my answer up if it helped you or gave you some idea (please  :)  )

Comment: @water I also see that you suggested an edit to my answer, that was rejected (not by me) . Great, please go ahead and post it as answer to your own question [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This way some one else with a similar question can also benefit from the answer you found your self!

Comment: @water I kept the text of your edit for you. Tell me if you want it. you can just post an empty answer then I will send back your own text as an edit. this way you don't have to rewrite it! Just remind me if you choose to do this!

Comment: thanks for your great support, I agree with you, let people who have similar question can benefit from it. Just do as you mentioned. Thanks you.